# Testing library React - expect multiple elements to pass a specified condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I have multiple buttons in my component and all of them should be disabled.

```
const buttons = screen.getAllByRole('button');

expect(ALL BUTTONS).toHaveAttribute('disabled'); // I want something like this.
```

How can we write this in the most convenient way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Iterate the buttons array and run the expect for each one

```
buttons.forEach((button) => {
   expect(button).toHaveAttribute('disabled');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this code in my test:

```
buttons.forEach((button) =>{
    expect(button).toBeDisabled()
})
```

or you can write this:

```
 expect(buttons).toBeDisabled().toHaveLength(2)//here you put number of your buttons
```

Comment: The second one is a short and convenient way as well, thank you, sir!